# Boost::python Exposing C++ functions using and returning templates

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I need to build python bindings for a C++ codebase. I use boost::python and I ran into problems trying to expose classes containing functions using and returning templates. Here is a typical example

```
class Foo 
{ 
    public: 
        Foo(); 
        template<typename T> Foo& setValue(
            const string& propertyName, const T& value); 
        template<typename T> const T& getValue(
            const string& propertyName); 
};
```

Typical T are string, double, vector.

After reading the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html), I tried using thin wrappers for every type used. Here are the wrappers for string and double and the corresponding class declaration.

```
Foo & (Foo::*setValueDouble)(const std::string&,const double &) = 
    &Foo::setValue; 
const double & (Foo::*getValueDouble)(const std::string&) = 
    &Foo::getValue;

Foo & (Foo::*setValueString)(const std::string&,const std::string &) = 
    &Foo::setValue; 
const std::string & (Foo::*getValueString)(const std::string&) = 
    &Foo::getValue;

class_<Foo>("Foo") 
    .def("setValue",setValueDouble, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()) 
    .def("getValue",getValueDouble,
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()) 
    .def("getValue",getValueString, 
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()) 
    .def("setValue",setValueString, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

It compiles ok but when I try to use the python bindings, I get a C++ exception.

```
>>> f = Foo()  
>>> f.setValue("key",1.0) 
>>> f.getValue("key") 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ? 
  RuntimeError: unidentifiable C++ exception
```

Interestingly, when I only expose Foo for double or string value, i.e

```
class_<Foo>("Foo") 
    .def("getValue",getValueString, 
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()) 
    .def("setValue",setValueString, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

It works fine.
Am I missing something?

Comment: you might want to look at the thread at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2006-February/009990.html (which tackles a similar problem: wrapping boost::any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be related to your problem directly but I would not trust function signature casting with templates like that. I would have wrapped it like this:

```
class_<Foo>("Foo") 
    .def("setValue", &Foo::setValue<double>, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()) 
    .def("getValue", &Foo::getValue<double>,
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()) 
    .def("getValue", &Foo::getValue<std::string>, 
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>()) 
    .def("setValue", &Foo::setValue<std::string>, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

If that does not work, you may need to create some shim functions:

```
Foo& setValueDouble(foo& self, const string& propertyName, const double value)
{ 
    return self.setValue(propertyName, value)
}
...
```

and export those as thought they were member functions.

Exporting multiple function overloads to the same name is a perfectly valid thing to do in Boost::Python, so I do not think that that is the problem.

Comment: I don't see any casting in the code in the question.  That's how you declare a variable of type "pointer-to-member-function".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that boost::python does not know which overload to call for "getValue" - should it call getValueDouble or getValueString?   If you bind them explicitly as getValueString and getValueDouble (as the method name) I bet it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried what you suggest and it worked. But it makes the resulting python code more verbose since I have to use different getter depending on the value type. Maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: This should not be necessary. Exporting multiple signatures to the same name is a perfectly valid thing to do in in Boost::Python.

Comment: @Louis: I don't understand how you want python to know which overload you want... Even in C++, you have to be verbose (as you say) by specifying the type: `foo.getValue<double>(...)`

Comment: @rafak. You are correct. Thank you. I guess my C++ knowledge is a bit rusty right now.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a C++ wrappers for getters/setters that return/take a boost::python::object?  You can then simply determine the type you got in your C++ wrapper and wrap/unwrap it into/from boost::python::object.

```
struct FooWrap : public Foo
{
    using boost::python;
    Foo& setValueO(const string& propertyName, const object& obj)
    {
        object value;
        if(PyInt_Check(obj.ptr())) {
            return setValue<int>(propertyName, extract<int>(obj);
        } else if(PyFloat_Check(obj.ptr())) {
            return setValue<double>(propertyName, extract<double>(obj);
        } else if(PyString_Check(obj.ptr())) {
            return setValue<std::string>(propertyName, extract<std::string>(obj);
        }
        // etc...
    }

    object getValueO(const std::string& propertyName)
    {
        if(determineType() == TYPE_INT) { // however you determine the type
            return object(getValue<int>(propertyName));
        } else if(determineType() == TYPE_DOUBLE)   {
            return object(getValue<double>(propertyName));
        } else if(determineType() == TYPE_STRING)   {
            return object(getValue<std::string>(propertyName));
        }
        // etc...
    }
};

class_<Foo>("Foo") 
    .def("setValue", &FooWrap::setValueO, 
        return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()) 
    .def("getValue", &FooWrap::getValueO,
        return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
```